# SASS : How to generate a map using a loop

Tags: css, loops, sass, sass-maps

My goal is to generate a SASS `map` to store variants of colors that are stored in the following map:

```
  $colors : (

    jet                 : #333333,
    wintergreen-dream   : #588C73,
    eton-blue           : #8FC0A9,
    sunglow             : #FFC33C,
    light-kaki          : #F2E394,
    bege                : #FAF3DD

  );
```

So far, I am using a `@function` to retrieve these variants:

```
  @function light       ($color, $val) { @return lighten($color, $val);     }
  @function dark        ($color, $val) { @return darken($color, $val);      }
  @function transparent ($color, $val) { @return transparent($color, $val); }
```

The map I am expecting to be able to generate would look alike the following:

```
  $colors-map : (

    eton-blue : (

        base  : $eton-blue,
        light : lighten($eton-blue, 15%),
        dark  : darken($eton-blue, 15%),
        trans : transparent($eton-blue, .5)


    ),

    jet : (

      base  : $jet,
      light : lighten($jet, 15%),
      dark  : darken($jet, 15%),
      trans : transparent($jet, .5)

    )

    // ...

  );
```

Yet, the loop I've already tried to apply, looks like this:

```
@for $key, $value in $colors {}
```

However, I was naive to believe it could work inside of the map itself.

**Questions which answers could easier answer this doubt** :

- How to add values to a SASS map (function), (key:value) ?
- Basic usage of `map-merge`/`map-set` ? (`@return map-merge($map, $new)`)

Strictly what I am looking for below :

```
$alternative-colors : (

    @each $color, $hex in $colors {

        #{$color} : (

            light : lighten($color, 25%),
            dark  : darken($color, 25%)

        );

    }

);
```

But yet, it returns following error:

```
Error: Invalid CSS after \"...tive-colors : (\": expected \")\", was \"@each (...)
```

**Conclusion**

Long time have passed, and I it would be nice if I could share my solution with everyone else.

I have created a repo to store the results of this problem solving, https://github.com/vladimirlisovets/SASS-Color-Palettes.

Hope it to be useful to someone either to inspire for something better.

Cheers.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
$colors : (
  jet                 : #333333,
  wintergreen-dream   : #588C73,
  eton-blue           : #8FC0A9,
  sunglow             : #FFC33C,
  light-kaki          : #F2E394,
  bege                : #FAF3DD
);

$colors-map: ();

@function create_colour_map($color, $percentage, $opacity) {
  $map: (
    base: $color,
    light: lighten($color, $percentage),
    dark: darken($color, $percentage),
    trans: transparentize($color, $opacity)
  );
  @return $map;
}

@each $key, $value in $colors {
  $map: ();
  $map: map-merge($map, ($key: create_colour_map($value, 15%, 0.5)) );
  $colors-map: map-merge($colors-map, $map);
}

@debug $colors-map; //prints out the map below 
  (jet:               (base: #333333, 
                       light: #595959,
                       dark: #0d0d0d,
                       trans: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.5)), 
   wintergreen-dream: (base: #588C73, 
                       light: #81b099,
                       dark: #3a5d4c,
                       trans: rgba(88, 140, 115, 0.5)),
   eton-blue:          (base: #8FC0A9,
                        light: #c0dccf,
                        dark: #5ea483,
                        trans: rgba(143, 192, 169, 0.5)), 
   sunglow:            (base: #FFC33C,
                        light: #ffdb89,
                        dark: #efa500,
                        trans: rgba(255, 195, 60, 0.5)),
   light-kaki:         (base: #F2E394,
                        light: #faf5d8,
                        dark: #ead150,
                        trans: rgba(242, 227, 148, 0.5)),
   bege:               (base: #FAF3DD,
                        light: white,
                        dark: #f0db9a,
                        trans: rgba(250, 243, 221, 0.5)))
```

I merged your three functions into one, the `create_colour_map` function. It takes three arguments for the `colour`, `percentage` and `opacity`. The function returns a `map`

Calling the `create_colour_map(#333333, 15%, 0.5)` with those args returns a `map`

```
(base: #333333, 
 light: #595959,
 dark: #0d0d0d,
 trans: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.5)
);
```

I just loop through the `$colors` map and each time call the function which generates a map that becomes the value of the key each time for an iteration.

> **How to add values to a map and basic usage of map-merge?**

I use `map-merge` to add values to a `map`. Just as the name implies, it joins two maps together and since it is a function, it can be used where Sass expects a *value*. So take for example the code below

```
$map: ( colour: red);
$new_map: (class: blue);
```

If we wanted `$map` to have the same keys and values as both maps, we could write

```
$map: map-merge( $map, $new_map); // $map: (colour: red, class: blue)
```

This is basically saying the `return` value of the function ( which would be the two maps joined together ) is the value of `$map`

Simply put just think of that line of code as ***variable reassignment*** in programming languages. This is how you can use `map-merge` to set values in maps. The 2nd argument for the `map-merge` method doesn't need to be a predefined map variable. It could have been written this way

```
$map: map-merge( $map, (class: blue) );
```

So here it just looks like you're adding a new `key` and `value` to the `$map` variable

Comment: Wonderful! It works so well! Thank you, I will be working on this solution further so I could create color palettes and manage them alongside the pages.

Comment: Hope more people with the same problem find this solution ^^

Comment: You're very welcome. And thanks for the edit, I just happened to miss that bit when I was refactoring to ensure my naming convention was sensible :)

Comment: Strange, I used a similar logic and it does not work with `map-set`, but worked when I changed it to `map-merge`. The documentation says they both return a new map, but it did not seem to work for me. Could just be my version of node-sass.

Answer (score -1):

Simply do it like this.

color name & hex pair:

```
$colors: (
  "primary": #404145,
  "secondary": #F5F0F6,
  "yellow": #ecaf2d,
  "green": #5ad864,
  "danger": #B0413E,
  "grey": #808A9F,
  "black": #000F08,
  "white": #ffffff,
);
```

create mixin (reusable), $attribute is a variable, default to color. we can pass its value while calling this mixin.

```
@mixin bg-mixin($attribute: 'color') { 

  @each $name,
  $hex in $colors {
    &-#{$name} {
      #{$attribute}: $hex;
    }
  }
}
```

Using it to generate text color and background color.

```
.text {
  @include bg-mixin();
}
```

generated classes will be text-primary, text-secondary and so on.

```
.bg {
  @include bg-mixin($attribute: 'background-color');
}
```

generated classes will be bg-primary, bg-secondary and so on.